# PyQt QSqlQuery.prepare() returns false

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qsqlquery, qsqldatabase

In PyQt4 I create a `QSqlDatabase` like

```
slpath = 'path/to/my/db.sqlite'
db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSPATIALITE')
db.setDatabaseName(slpath)
```

This seem to work. Now I try to `UPDATE` a table `layer_styles` as follows:

```
query = QSqlQuery(db) #db cp. above
query.prepare("UPDATE layer_styles SET f_table_catalog=:path;")
query.bindValue(":path", slpath)
query.exec_()
```

But the `query.prepare(...)` returns `false`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a [built-in database driver](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/sql-driver.html#supported-databases) called "QSPATIALITE", but your QGIS installation may provide a custom [SpatiaLite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpatiaLite) driver with that name. This driver is an extension to sqlite, so you can use it like this:

```
slpath = 'path/to/my/db.sqlite'
if QSqlDatabase.isDriverAvailable('QSPATIALITE'):
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSPATIALITE')
else:
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
db.setDatabaseName(slpath)
if not db.open():
    print('ERROR:', db.lastError().text())
```

If `prepare()` or `exec_()` still fail, you can use `query.lastError()` to check for mistakes in the sql statement.

Comment: At least from inside PyQGIS QSPATIALITE works fine, even if not in the standard drivers. I got this from the answer to this post https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167707/connecting-qgis-spatialite-and-python I simply forgot `db.open()`...

Comment: @JochenSchwarze. Thanks. I did suspect it may be a custom driver, but for some reason I could not find any information about it, so I drew the wrong conclusions. I have amended my answer accordingly.